# I'm using ROS noetic over wsl in Windows 11, but rospy library is not loaded in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ros, rospy

This is the error I get through the terminal, I wonder if vs code and ros are not integrated vs code because I installed it through windows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To work properly with VSCode you need to install the [ROS VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros). The wiki also currently [has an entry for VSCode support.](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Visual_Studio_Code_.28VSCode.29)